# Transforming a regression model with dummy into two models

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares

Consider the following regression model:

\begin{equation}
y = \alpha + \beta X + \gamma D + \epsilon,
\end{equation}

where $y$ is the dependent variable, $X$ is a continuous variable, $D$ is a dummy variable and $\epsilon$ is the error term.

Now, suppose we decompose our dataset into two subsets where $D$ is either one or zero, and we denote the dependent variable as $y_{1}$ and $y_{0}$, respectively. Therefore, constructing the following models:

\begin{equation}
y_{1} = \alpha^{'} + \beta^{'} X + \epsilon^{'},
\end{equation}

and,

\begin{equation}
y_{0} = \alpha^{''} + \beta^{''} X + \epsilon^{''},
\end{equation}

and then using OLS to estimate those three models, separately, we come up with $\hat{\beta}, \hat{\beta^{'}}$ and $\hat{\beta^{''}}$. Now, my question is whether or not we can draw the following conclusion:

\begin{equation}
\hat{\beta^{'}} < \hat{\beta} < \hat{\beta^{''}},
\end{equation}

Or,

\begin{equation}
\hat{\beta^{'}} > \hat{\beta} > \hat{\beta^{''}}.
\end{equation}

Thanks!